# htaccess rewrite images url for seo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, google-search

i'm trying to rewrite my images URL to get better google rankings. Problem is that i also need to pass GET variables in the URL

Currently my images URL looks like this:
https://www.mydomain.com/image_zoom.php?img=18418294&var=2&color=2&keywords=t-shirt

I want an URL like this instead:
https://www.mydomain.com/image/18418294/2/t-shirt.png

Is it possible to do this easily with htaccess ?

Also, for google images SEO is it better to put the revelent keywords inside the filename or the folder name ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: i'm also asking about htaccess.

Comment: Which also belongs on another Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_zoom.php?img=$1&var=$2&color=$2&keywords=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```